# Angular 6: table with *ngIF generates one <td> more than i need

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a table with `*ngFor` that I iterate the array, in this table I want to show the values but if the values are null I want to show a character `-` but my `*ngIf` generate a `<td>`more that i need.

**My table:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of servicesFiltered; let i = index">
   <td class="values-left">{{ item.scheduleDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
   <td *ngIf="!item.customer.name"> - </td> 
   <td class="values-left">{{ item.customer.name }}</td>
   <td *ngIf="!item.service.name"> - </td>
   <td class="values-left">{{item.service.name}}</td>
   <td *ngIf="!item.employee.name"> - </td>
   <td *ngIf="userCheck == true" class="values-left">{{item.employee.name}}</td>
   <td *ngIf="!item.value"> - </td> 
   <td class="values-right">{{item.value | currency:curSymbol}}</td>
   <td *ngIf="!item.comissionValue"> - </td> 
   <td *ngIf="userCheck == true"  class="values-right">{{item.comissionValue | currency:curSymbol}}</td>                  
</tr>
```

The lines that i have `<td *ngIf="!item.comissionValue"> - </td>` break my table. How can i show that character without break my table?

Comment: Anyway, each row of a table must have the same number of `<td>` in order to not break. Use a different method. Hard code the `<td>` so their number is always correct, and apply `*ngIf` to the _content_ of the cells, not to the cells themselves.

Comment: how can i do this @JeremyThille ?

Comment: Well, exactly like I said :) Hard code your correct number of `<td>`, then put something inside, like a `<div>`, and apply `*ngIf` to the div, not to the cell.

Comment: If the cells contain only text, I suggest applying the `ngIf` to an `ng-container` element, which is not rendered in the HTML output.

Comment: Use conditional operator, e.g. < td [ngClass]="{'values-left':item.customer.name}>{{item.customer.name?item.customer.name:'-'}}< /td>

Comment: I supouse you can use pipe too (but I don't know, sorry) try {{item.value? item.value | currency:curSymbol : '-'}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider combining the `<td>` so that you have fewer cells, but they are displayed together:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of servicesFiltered; let i = index">
   <td class="values-left">{{ item.scheduleDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
   <td class="values-left" *ngIf="!item.customer.name"> - {{ item.customer.name }}</td>
   <td class="values-left" *ngIf="!item.service.name"> - {{item.service.name}}</td>
   <td class="values-left" *ngIf="!item.employee.name && userCheck == true"> - {{item.employee.name}}</td>
   <td class="values-right" *ngIf="!item.value"> - {{item.value | currency:curSymbol}}</td>
   <td class="values-right" *ngIf="!item.comissionValue && userCheck == true"> - {{item.comissionValue | currency:curSymbol}}</td>                  
</tr>
```

If you want to keep the same number of cells, then consider using `<ng-container>` with `ngIf` inside `<td>`:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of servicesFiltered; let i = index">
   <td class="values-left">{{ item.scheduleDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
   <td><ng-container *ngIf="!item.customer.name"> - <ng-container></td> 
   <td class="values-left">{{ item.customer.name }}</td>
   <td><ng-container *ngIf="!item.service.name"> - <ng-container></td>
   <td class="values-left">{{item.service.name}}</td>
   <td><ng-container *ngIf="!item.employee.name"> - <ng-container></td>
   <td><ng-container *ngIf="userCheck == true" class="values-left">{{item.employee.name}}<ng-container></td>
   <td><ng-container *ngIf="!item.value"> - <ng-container></td> 
   <td class="values-right">{{item.value | currency:curSymbol}}</td>
   <td><ng-container *ngIf="!item.comissionValue"> - <ng-container></td> 
   <td><ng-container *ngIf="userCheck == true"  class="values-right">{{item.comissionValue | currency:curSymbol}}<ng-container></td>                  
</tr>
```

Lastly, if you want to stick with the plan of having varying numbers of `<td>`'s, then you should go over the if conditions more carefully. Your issue may be due to the conditions not distinguishing between null values and 0/false values.